# legacy django code: request first parameter in all methods

Tags: django, refactoring, legacy-code

I need to deal with legacy django code.

Nearly all methods have `request` as first parameter. Not only views, that's ok there.

The `request` is passed along only to get request.user and to permission checks against the current active user.

I don't see a good solution to solve this mess.

There are tests, but I would like to refactor the code.

Removing `request` from the method definitions does not work, since the current active user needs to be accessed.

**Update**

`request` is accessed in:

- views (OK for me)
- forms (not OK for me)
- utility methods (not OK for me)

`models` don't use request in this code (good for me).

Comment: In which layers is the request accessed? is it in views? models? forms?

Comment: @petkostas thank you for our feedback. I updated the question

Comment: Request in forms is used if the form needs to deal with it. If you believe this needs refactoring, you could create a base class that assigns the request in an attribute and access it from there eg `self.request`, mind though that this requires request to be injected in the form so it doesn't save you much but allows you to use a common attribute to access the request information.
Utility methods on the other hand, could call a centralized function / method to get the request and acquire the necessary details, this way future refactoring would require you to touch only the central function.

Comment: If the logic required from request inside forms can be refactored to another layer (views?) you can also do that, but I can't really help you more since no details are provided of what kind of logic is performed inside your forms / utilities.